# restrict firebase analytics sent events to google analytics based on bundle id

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, firebase-analytics, ionic6, google-api-key-restrictions

I have created an Ionic application using [firebase analytics plugin](https://github.com/chemerisuk/cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics) , and I am sending google analytics events through this plugin and it works fine.
I wanted to restrict the events that I am getting into my GA account to be only from my application bundle id (for example com.odai) and no other applications can send events from the same firebase account

I tried to restrict the api key to get events only from this bundle using https://console.cloud.google.com/ but didnt work (if there are any applications with different bundle id but the same firebase account will still get those events in google analytics)
I added restrictions to the API keys and  OAuth 2.0 Client ID but with no luck
is there any other way to achieve that ?